# How do I connect velostat to an arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have some [velostat](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1361) that I'd like to hook up to an Uno. At the risk of sounding dense...how do I do that?

Ultimately wanting to get readings of pressure from the velostat, just not sure how or what wires to connect where.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a variable resistance sensor is used in a voltage divider circuit:

[image]

In the above example a thermistor is connected to the positive supply and a pull down R1 is connected to ground.  The voltage where they meet is measured using one of the Arduino's analog inputs pins.

Choosing R1 is tricky.  If it is too large compared to the variable resistance sensor the voltage fluctuation at Vout will be too small to measure.  The same problem exists if R1 is too small compared to the variable resistance sensor.  Also, you need to mind the current through the sensor.  If the combined resistance of R1 and the sensor is too small the current may damage the sensor, over heat R1 and / or put a heavy drain on your power source.